# Django Transaction Management with DEBUG = True

Tags: django, django-database

Transactions are working correctly in production environment (django 1.9 + Ubuntu + PosgreSQL) but they have no effect in development environment with DEBUG = True.

E.g.

```
with transaction.atomic()
   do_stuff()
   raise Exception()
```

Changes made to DB by do_stuff() are supposed to be rolled back because of the exception. This happens in production environment as expected.

In dev environment changes made by do_stuff are not rolled back. I can't find any explanation of this behaviour in django docs.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Which is it: "thay have no effect in development environment" or "are still there in dev environment but not in production environment"?

Comment: I think you need to add more detail about how to reproduce the problem. There's nothing in the pseudo code you have shown that would explain that behaviour.